# Trying to remove my backgroundTint colour

Tags: android-studio

I can't seem to remove the `backgroundTint`. When I try deleting it, it continues to be on purple

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you are using material so material pick your primary colour.
simple add backgroundTint colour transparent otherwise it automatically pick your app primary colour in colour.xml